# Identifying arrays with the same mean

Tags: python, java, array

I came across a problem where given a array of integer arrays of different lengths `[[1,2,3],[4,1,1], [9,2,1]]` you need to return an array of arrays, each array containing indices of the arrays (of the input array) such that the corresponding arrays have the same mean: `[[0,1],[2]]` This seems relatively simple to solve using Python:

```
def groupByMean(a):
    d,e=[],[]
    for i,j in enumerate(a):
        if sum(j)/len(j)not in e:
            e+=[sum(j)/len(j)]
            d+=[[i]]
        else:
            d[e.index(sum(j)/len(j))]+=[i]
    return d
```

However, when trying to solve this in Java this was my approach: using a hashmap, map each new mean to a list of the corresponding indices. Then iterate the hashmap, to get the arraylists and convert them to int[] arrays and construct the 2d array ...

Is there a simpler approach to solve this using Java?

This is my java code - looking for a different way to solve this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 4 }, { 2, 4, 0 } };
    for (int[] nums : groupBySum(arr)) {
        for (int n : nums) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int[][] groupByMean(int[][] arr) {
    Map<Double, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (int[] nums : arr) {
        double average = getAverage(nums);
        if (!map.containsKey(average)) {
            List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
            indices.add(i);
            map.put(average, indices);
        } else {
            map.get(average).add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    int[][] result = new int[map.size()][];
    int row = 0;
    for (List<Integer> indices : map.values()) {
        result[row] = new int[indices.size()];
        for (int k = 0; k < indices.size(); k++) {
            result[row][k] = indices.get(k);
        }
        row++;
    }
    return result;
}

public static double getAverage(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num : arr) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return ((double) sum) / arr.length;
}
```

Comment: Please state in the title what your code does. You can find more info on [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What if the input array is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice implementation. Few suggestions to make the method `groupByMean` more compact using Java Streams:

- **Calculate the average**:

  ```
  public static double getAverage(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num : arr) {
        sum += num;
    }
    return ((double) sum) / arr.length;
  }
  ```

  To:

  ```
  public static double getAverage(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums).average().getAsDouble();
  }
  ```
- **Group by average**:

  ```
  if (!map.containsKey(average)) {
      List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
      indices.add(i);
      map.put(average, indices);
  } else {
      map.get(average).add(i);
  }
  ```

  To:

  ```
  map.computeIfAbsent(average, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
  ```
- **Convert list to array**:

  ```
  for (int k = 0; k < indices.size(); k++) {
      result[row][k] = indices.get(k);
  }
  ```

  To:

  ```
  result[row] = indices.stream().mapToInt(index->index).toArray();
  ```
- **Convert map's values to a matrix**:

  ```
  int[][] result = new int[map.size()][];
  int row = 0;
  for (List<Integer> indices : map.values()) {
      result[row] = new int[indices.size()];
      for (int k = 0; k < indices.size(); k++) {
          result[row][k] = indices.get(k);
      }
      row++;
  }
  return result;
  ```

  To:

  ```
  return map.values().stream()
            .map(v -> v.stream().mapToInt(index->index).toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
  ```

### Time/Space Complexity

In terms of complexity there are no relevant differences between your solution and the one using Streams. The time complexity is still \$O(n*m)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of arrays and \$m\$ is the size of the longest array. Basically, for each array we need to calculate the average.

To check which approach is faster you need to benchmark the solutions.

### Final code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 4 }, { 2, 4, 0 }};
    Arrays.stream(groupByMean(arr)).map(Arrays::toString)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static int[][] groupByMean(int[][] arr) {
    Map<Double, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
        double average = Arrays.stream(arr[i]).average().getAsDouble();
        map.computeIfAbsent(average, v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
    }
    return map.values().stream()
      .map(v -> v.stream().mapToInt(index->index).toArray())
      .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! What are the advantages in terms of time/space complexity?

Comment: @beginnercs12 I am glad I could help ;). I updated my answer to answer your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the `groupingBy` collector.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3, 4 }, { 2, 4, 0 }};
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(i->Arrays.stream(arr[i]).average().getAsDouble()))
        .values()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```